# What is the fastest way to iterate through a pandas DataFrame to create custom objects?

Tags: python, pandas

My use case is this:
I have a pandas DataFrame that was loaded from an SQL database. I want to construct an object from every row.
You'd maybe think you'd want to use df.apply, but this is actually extremely slow as demonstrated later.
I don't know what the fastest way to accomplish this would be.

To figure out what was fastest, I constructed a repo that tests various functions that does this, but I don't know if I might be missing something.

My test setup is as follows:

Create a list of functions that takes as input a DataFrame and outputs a list of `Node` objects.

Set a random seed so every function gets the same input DataFrame.

Construct a DataFrame of size N (from 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, 2048, 4096, 8192, 16384, 32768).

This DataFrame is then passed into our test functions that calls a function with the following signature: `create_node(b, a, f, e, d, c, g)` or `create_node_ignored_args(b, a, f, e, d, c, g, *args, **kwargs)`.

These functions create a `Node` object (class `__init__` signature: `def __init__(self, node_id, b, a, f, c, d, e, g)`).

Note that the DataFrame contains these columns `b, a, f, e, d, c, g`, but not in that order.

It's important that we be able to pass arguments in the correct order or the `Node` will be incorrectly constructed.

For example if you have a DataFrame: `{"a":1, "b":2, "c":3, "d":4, "e":5, "f":6: "g":{"subset": [1,2,3,4]}}` and you just naively pass that into `create_node` as *args you'll end up with an incorrect `Node` where the `b` field in the object is set to `a` and so forth.

This can be avoided if you pass in the arguments as `**kwargs`, which will match the columns in the DataFrame with the exact arguments in the function.

Note that if you have too many columns in the DataFrame then calling `create_node` with all of them will fail because of too many arguments, which is why we also have `create_node_ignored_args` which can ignore args/kwargs if there's too many args or non-matching kwargs.

Here are a few example functions:

```py
def index_df_apply(df):
    """Use apply, get the fields indexing using LOOKUP.

    Use as args in create_node (using *).
    """
    nodes = df.apply(lambda row: create_node(*row[LOOKUP]), axis=1)
    return [node for node in nodes]

def itertuples(df):
    """Loop over itertuples, convert namedtuple to dict, get fields using tuple_unwrap fn according to LOOKUP.

    Use as kwargs in create_node (using **).
    """
    nodes = []
    for row in df.itertuples(index=False):
        nodes.append(create_node(**tuple_unwrap(row, LOOKUP)))
    return nodes

def zip_comprehension_lookup(df):
    """List comprehension over zipped df columns, get fields using * and LOOKUP.

    Use as args in create_node (using *).
    """
    nodes = [create_node(*args) for args in zip(*(df[c] for c in LOOKUP))]
    return nodes
```

We have two cases we want to test: Performance for large DataFrames over less iterations, and performance for small DataFrames over many iterations. We'll visualize the one for large DataFrames over less iterations and provide a text report as well, but only provide text report for the small DataFrames over many iterations.

For the large DataFrames 1 iteration, we can create two straight-forward perfplot images:

[image: Perfplot with relative timings to the fastest function]
[image: Perfplot with absolute timings]

Here's some roughly equivalent timing data for these images: https://github.com/Atheuz/pandas-to-object-perf-test/blob/master/time_one_iteration_count.txt

From this timing test, we see that the fastest functions are: zip_comprehension_np_values_lookup, zip_comprehension_lookup, zip_comprehension_direct_access, to_numpy_direct_access, itertuples_direct_access_comprehension.

These are those functions:

```py
def zip_comprehension_np_values_lookup(df):
    """List comprehension over zipped df columns, get fields using *, LOOKUP, use .values.

    Use as args in create_node (using *).
    """
    nodes = [create_node(*args) for args in zip(*(df[c].values for c in LOOKUP))]
    return nodes

def zip_comprehension_direct_access(df):
    """List comprehension over zip object, get fields using direct indexing.

    Use as args in create_node (using *).
    """
    nodes = [create_node(*args) for args in zip(df["b"], df["a"], df["f"], df["e"], df["d"], df["c"], df["g"])]
    return nodes

def zip_comprehension_lookup(df):
    """List comprehension over zipped df columns, get fields using * and LOOKUP.

    Use as args in create_node (using *).
    """
    nodes = [create_node(*args) for args in zip(*(df[c] for c in LOOKUP))]
    return nodes

def to_numpy_direct_access(df):
    """Get the names of columns in our dataframe, create indices lookup from name->idx, convert df to numpy and access fields using indices lookup.

    Use as kwargs in create_node (using direct assignment).
    """
    cols = list(df.columns)
    indices = {k: cols.index(k) for k in cols}
    nodes = [
        create_node(
            b=row[indices["b"]],
            a=row[indices["a"]],
            f=row[indices["f"]],
            e=row[indices["e"]],
            d=row[indices["d"]],
            c=row[indices["c"]],
            g=row[indices["g"]],
        )
        for row in df.to_numpy()
    ]
    return nodes

def itertuples_direct_access_comprehension(df):
    """List comprehension over itertuples, get fields accessing them directly.

    Use as kwargs in create_node (using direct assignment).
    """
    nodes = [create_node(b=row.b, a=row.a, f=row.f, e=row.e, d=row.d, c=row.c, g=row.g) for row in df.itertuples(index=False)]
    return nodes
```

Similarly, a text report for the other case where we want to test small DataFrames with a high iteration count: https://github.com/Atheuz/pandas-to-object-perf-test/blob/master/time_high_iteration_count.txt

From this timing test, it appears that the fastest functions are these:

zip_comprehension_np_values_lookup, zip_comprehension_direct_access, zip_comprehension_lookup, to_numpy_direct_access, to_numpy_take

The only new function for this case is: to_numpy_take

```py
def to_numpy_take(df):
    """Get the names of columns in our dataframe, create indices lookup from name->idx using LOOKUP, convert df to numpy and access fields using the indices lookup using np.take.

    Use as args in create_node (using *).
    """
    cols = list(df.columns)
    indices = [cols.index(k) for k in LOOKUP]
    nodes = [create_node(*np.take(row, indices)) for row in df.to_numpy()]
    return nodes
```

For more information you can visit my GitHub repo here: https://github.com/Atheuz/pandas-to-object-perf-test

Anyway, my question still stands: Is there a generally recommended fast way to create objects from pandas DataFrames, or did I accidentally find it? access the DataFrame columns you want and zip them together. I'm also very confused about why `df.apply(lambda row: create_node(*row[LOOKUP]), axis=1)` is actually one of the slowest ways to accomplish this.

Comment: Surely the answer is going to be "there is no one fastest way, but a bunch of ways that are better or worse than others depending on the context"?

Comment: However, this is a great collection of different ways to iterate a dataframe which also compares the performance.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your tests, it appears that the fastest way to create objects from a pandas DataFrame is to access the desired columns and use zip to combine them into arguments for your object constructor. Specifically, the following functions performed well in your tests:

- `zip_comprehension_np_values_lookup`
- `zip_comprehension_direct_access`
- `zip_comprehension_lookup`
- `to_numpy_direct_access`
- `to_numpy_take`

It's not entirely clear why `df.apply(lambda row: create_node(*row[LOOKUP]), axis=1)` was one of the slowest approaches in your testing. One possible explanation is that `apply` creates a lot of overhead since it's essentially looping through the DataFrame and applying a function to each row. On the other hand, the other approaches you tested are more efficient since they access the desired columns directly and use zip to combine them.