# unbalanced parenthesis at position. (find index problem)

Tags: python, pandas

Here is my sample table.

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'sentence': {0: 'idontlike)anap:ple.dislike)', 1: 'welcomet)omyroom.plzcomein', 2: 'thisis)thetable'},   'target': {0: 'like)', 1: 'come', 2: 'is)'}}               )
```

and as you can see, some of target columns have a single ")".

what I want to extract is, find exact index of the target word from each sentence. (Allow duplication.)

For example, the index of the first row should be 5, 20 (because "like)" is in the sentence TWICE).

I already know that I can use bleow code,(asked stackoverflow before)

```
df.apply(lambda x: [m.start() for m in re.finditer(x.target,x.sentence)], axis=1)
```

but since the single ")" is included in some sentences,

```
error: unbalanced parenthesis at position 4
```

this error keeps comming out.

And, plz don't consider of using "split" for the sentence. I don't want any spaces. Also, The table has to have the ")".

Comment: The error is because you're using `re.find()`, which requires a well-formed regular expression.  Why are you using `re.find()` anyway?  Why not just the regular string `.find()` method?

Comment: @JohnGordon I expect because there is no `str.finditer`, and just using `re.finditer` is less hassle than writing couple more lines to implement the looping logic using `str.find`.

Comment: Shouldn't the output for the first row be 5, 22 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `re` (regular expressions) for your search, your "search term" needs to be a valid regex. Either change manually `'like)'` to `r'like\)'`, if you want to be able to have regex semantics in your search, or [escape](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.escape) it automatically:

```
df.apply(lambda x: [
    m.start() for m in re.finditer(re.escape(x.target), x.sentence)
], axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I spent almost 2days to solve this problem. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Taking the implementation of regular expressions from [Amadan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76519429/19060733) and referring the comparisons done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76502222/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-iterate-through-a-pandas-dataframe-to-create-custom-o)

A faster way of doing the same would be -

```
[
    [m.start() for m in re.finditer(re.escape(word), sentence)] for sentence, word in zip(*(df[c].values for c in df.columns)) 
]
```

The performance difference can be observed with-
[image: Comparing the performance of zip and apply]